# Ruby on Rails and SSL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I formatted my computer and transferred all my RoR applications to my new Lubuntu System.
I had Ubuntu with Unity. (still a linux system). I have installed rvm, ruby, rails, and they all work fine! I then run "bundle install" before actually running "rails s" to test my app.
This is what I get

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
```

Any help ?

This is what sudo apt-get install openssl gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libreadline-gplv2-dev git-man libncurses5-dev libnspr4-0d libtinfo-dev git libreadline5 zlib1g-dev liberror-perl libsqlite3-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: do have openssl installed? sudo apt-get install openssl

Comment: Consider looking at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642368/why-require-mongo-gives-me-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-openssl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the packages before installing the ruby version with RVM?

Try removing the ruby version, running

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
```

and then install ruby version again